# yuidoc - how to define a class method in an other file

Tags: javascript, documentation, yuidoc

I'm writing documentation with yuidoc. However, I have a class Model, which has one of its methods defined elsewhere. Here is some code to visualize the situation.
Assume I have a file model.js:

```
/**
 * @class Model
 * @constructor
 */
 window.Model = function(){}
 ....
```

And a file activerecord.js:

```
(function(){
    /**
     * @class ActiveRecord
     * @constructor
     window.ActiveRecord = function(){}
     ....
     /**
      * @method Model.hasMany
      * @param {Class} model
      */
     function hasMany(model) {}
})() ;
```

As you can see, the method 'hasMany' should show up under the class documentation of Model. However, it doesn't. Is something like this possible ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `@for` tag: http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/syntax/index.html#for

```
/**  
 * Some method "hasMany" disconnected from its class "Model".
 * 
 * @method hasMany  
 * @for Model
 * @param {Class} model 
 */
function hasMany(model) {}
```